# Los productos del carrito desaparecen al actualizar la pagina

Tags: javascript, filtro, local-storage

Hola a toda la comunidad, quería consultar acerca de este inconveniente que tengo. Al parecer es un error de novato, pero no logro dar con la solución.
Arme un ecommerce con un carrito de compras, detallo algunos datos para tener en cuenta:

- Tengo un fetch que pushea los objetos al array stock
- Tengo una funcion renderizarCarrito que arma la lista de productos dentro del contenedor carrito
- Dentro de esta funcion tengo un filtro que me trae el item que necesito desde el array stock
- Cada vez que se agrega un elemento al carrito, tambien se agregan al localStorage

Todo funciona bien, pero luego de agregar algun elemento al carrito y actualizar la pagina, los elementos que fueron agregados (que estan en el localStorage) no se pintan nuevamente. Tira error: app.js:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dis')

Hasta donde da mi conocimiento (limitado, por cierto) es que el problema esta en ese filtro y con el array stock, pero no me estoy dando cuenta que sucede.

Dejo la funcion renderizarCarrito para que puedan verla. Espero haber explicado bien el problema ya que es mi primer pregunta en stackoverflow.
Desde ya, muchas gracias a cualquier aporte

```js
 import { stock } from "./controllers/productsController.js";
 let carrito = [];
 const carritoDeCompras = document.getElementById('contenedor-carrito'); 
 const btnComprar = document.getElementById('boton-comprar');
 const carritoStorage = window.localStorage


 function renderizarCarrito() {
    carritoDeCompras.textContent = '';
    
    const carritoSinDuplicados = [...new Set(carrito)];

    carritoSinDuplicados.forEach((item) => {
    
        // Obtengo el item que necesito de la variable stock - creo que aca esta el error
        const miRemera = stock.filter((remerasStock) => {
            return remerasStock.id === parseInt(item);
    });

             const numeroUnidadesItem = carrito.reduce((total, itemId) => {
            return itemId === item ? total += 1 : total;
        }, 0);
        
        const remeraCarrito = document.createElement('li');
        remeraCarrito.classList.add('list-group-item', 'text-right', 'mx-2');
        remeraCarrito.textContent = `${numeroUnidadesItem} x ${miRemera[0].dis} -       ${miRemera[0].precio}${divisa}`;
        
        const botonEliminar = document.createElement('button');
        botonEliminar.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger', 'mx-5');
        botonEliminar.textContent = 'X';
        botonEliminar.style.marginLeft = '1rem';
        botonEliminar.dataset.item = item;
        botonEliminar.addEventListener('click', borrarItemCarrito);
        
        remeraCarrito.appendChild(botonEliminar);
        carritoDeCompras.appendChild(remeraCarrito);
    }) 
    contadorCarrito.innerText = carrito.length;
    contenedorTotal.textContent = calcularTotal();
}

 function agregarAlCarrito(evento) {
     carrito.push(evento.target.getAttribute('marcador'))
     renderizarCarrito();
     guardarCarritoEnStorage();
}

 function guardarCarritoEnStorage () {
 carritoStorage.setItem('carrito', JSON.stringify(carrito));
}

 function cargarCarritoDeStorage () {
    if (carritoStorage.getItem('carrito') !== null) {
    carrito = JSON.parse(carritoStorage.getItem('carrito'));
}
}


btnVaciarCarrito.addEventListener('click', vaciarCarrito);
btnComprar.addEventListener('click', comprar);

cargarCarritoDeStorage();
renderizarProductos();
renderizarCarrito();
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx. Ni idea dónde estará la variable `dis` que menciona el error. Igual, si quieres conservar lo que está en pantalla, debes guardarlo en localStorage o en la sesión o en alguna parte (y el código que muestras tampoco hace nada relacionado, aunque en la pregunta dices que lo haces). La idea es que el código sea un ejemplo mínimo verificable para no estar preguntándote por cosas que no se ven y ya hiciste (y de paso, sabemos si quedaron bien o es un error simple)

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Hola Alfabro! Gracias por tu respuesta. La variable es miRemera, dis es una clave del objeto que trae stock.
Me recomendas pegar todo el codigo de todos los modulos para que pueda verse todo lo que hace?

Comment: No. Te recomiendo [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) \m/

Comment: Probaste a hacer un consolelog del storage? Estas seguro que se guarda adecuadamente?

Comment: Hola Hernan! Si, se guarda correctamente